# Double linked List functions - Driver program failure

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node_t{
    int value;
    struct node_t *prev;
    struct node_t *next;
} Node;

typedef struct LinkedList{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
} LinkedList;

void clearing_space_for_LinkedList(LinkedList *ll){
    ll->head = NULL;
    ll->tail = NULL;
}

int empty_check(LinkedList *ll){
    if(ll->head == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

void add_element_at_the_beginning(LinkedList *ll, int new_value){
    Node *temporary = calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
    temporary->value = new_value;

    if (empty_check(ll)){
        temporary->next = NULL;
        temporary->prev = NULL;
        ll->head = temporary;
        ll->tail = temporary;
    }
    else{
        temporary->next = ll->head;
        temporary->prev = NULL;
        ll->head->prev = temporary;
        ll->head = temporary;
    }
}

void add_element_at_the_end(LinkedList *ll, int new_value){
    Node *temporary = calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
    temporary->value = new_value;

    if (empty_check(ll)){
        temporary->next = NULL;
        temporary->prev = NULL;
        ll->head = temporary;
        ll->tail = temporary;
    }
    else{
        temporary->next = NULL;
        temporary->prev = ll->tail;
        ll->tail->next = temporary;
        ll->tail = temporary;
    }
}


int eliminate_the_first_element(LinkedList *ll){
    Node *temporary = ll->head;
    ll->head = ll->head->next;
    ll->head->prev = NULL;

    int result = temporary->value;
    free(temporary);
    return result;
}

int eliminate_the_last_element(LinkedList *ll){
    Node *temporary = ll->tail;
    ll->tail = ll->tail->prev;
    ll->tail->next = NULL;

    free(temporary);
    return temporary->value;
}

void eliminate_the_single_element(LinkedList *ll){
    Node *temporary = ll->head;
    ll->head = NULL;
    ll->tail = NULL;
    free(temporary);
}

int add_element_on_another_spot(LinkedList *ll, int new_val){
    int position = 0;
    scanf("%d", &position);

    Node *new_node = calloc(1,sizeof(Node));    
    new_node->value = new_val;
    
    Node *iterator = ll->head;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < position; ++i){
        iterator = iterator->prev;
    }

    new_node->next = iterator;
    new_node->prev = iterator->prev;
    iterator->prev->next = new_node;
    iterator->prev = new_node;
}

void print_the_linked_list(LinkedList *ll){
    Node *curr = ll->head;

    while (curr){
        printf("%d, ", curr->value);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

LinkedList * ll;

int main(){
    clearing_space_for_LinkedList(ll);
    add_element_at_the_beginning(ll, 10);
    print_the_linked_list(ll);
}
```

When i try to run it i get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
Can someone explain why am i getting this message ?
And is my algorithm of creating and using double linked list rightly done ?
Also i am having hard time realizing really how to remove element?

Is the used function above correct for creating space for the list or this:

```
void clearing_space_for_LinkedList(LinkedList *linkedList) {
linkedList = (LinkedList*)calloc(1, sizeof(LinkedList));
linkedList->head = (Node*)calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
linkedList->tail = (Node*)calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
linkedList->head = NULL;
linkedList->tail = NULL;
}
```

Is it possible to create double linked list with arrays and if yes, how ?
Will just creating array for value in the typdef structure will work ?

Comment: You are splitting two definitions of your linked list based on whether it is empty or not; you have to check each time you modify the topology for both cases. You've started doing that (`empty_check`) but I think you stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Code has at least these problems:

**No NULL check**

`clearing_space_for_LinkedList(LinkedList *ll)` attempts `ll->head` even when `ll == NULL` which happens on OP's first call.

**Code fails on last node elimination**

`eliminate_the_first_element()` makes no provision for setting `ll->tail` to `NULL` should the last node get eliminated.

Similar problem with `eliminate_the_last_element()`.

Comment: Can u explain more detailed ( im newbie )

Comment: Should i delete `ll->head->prev = NULL`

Comment: @Димитър Милчев What is the value of  `ll` when `clearing_space_for_LinkedList(ll);` is called?

Comment: I dont even use eliminate functions in my driver func

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев: "Should i delete ll->head->prev = NULL" --> No.  Yet 1) `eliminate_the_first_element()` should also set the tail to `NULL` if it the only node left in the list  2) `eliminate_the_first_element()` should not attempt to delete anything is the list is already empty.

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев as the first line of `main` do: `ll = calloc(1,sizeof(*ll));`

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев "I dont even use eliminate functions in my driver func" --> OK, so that unused code has trouble as well as used code.

Comment: i understand - i made correction, but my code poops again

Comment: do i even need function for clearing_space_for_LinkedList()

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев Be fair, before asking more questions - still waiting on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72048798/double-linked-list-functions-driver-program-failiure/72048910?noredirect=1#comment127307101_72048910).